# Binding to Key-Value Property

Tags: wpf

I need to know how to bind to a particular value in a key-value collection that is a property of an object. For example, if I have a collection of "car" objects, each of which has a "engine values" property that is just a Dictionary of strings keyed by strings... how would I say, add a column to a ListView control that bound to the value of the dictionary element with a key of "cylinder count" within the "engine values" property of the "car" object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) for this task and pass the key as the ConverterParameter. Something like

```
public class GetKeyValueConveter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var collection = value as KeyValueCollection;
        var key = parameter as key;
        return collection[key];
    }
}
```